# Can I infer that $\sum_{i=1}^n p(A_i|A_j)=1$ from $\sum_{i=1}^n p(A_i)=1$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n p(A_i|A_j)=1$?

Tags: probability

I have $n$ events $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n p(A_i)=1,$$
i.e. the sum over $i$ of the probability that event $A_i$ occurs is $1$, and
$$\sum_{j=1}^n p(A_i|A_j)=1.$$
Can I infer that also $\sum_{i=1}^n p(A_i|A_j)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1=\sum_j P(A_i|A_j)=1+\sum_{j\neq i} P(A_i|A_j)$ since $P(A_i|A_i)=1$. This gives $P(A_i \cap A_j)=0$ whenever $i \neq j$. Hence $1=\sum_i P(A_i|A_j)=1+\sum_{i\neq j} P(A_i|A_j)=1+0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the summation you get P(Ai|A1)+...+P(Ai|Ai)+...=1
But P(Ai|Ai)= 1.
Sum of other probabilities is 0 means they are all individually 0. And this holds for all i. So all these events are mutually exclusive and exhaustive events (as sum of individual probabilities is 1).
Hence, in the final inference sum, open the summation to get 0+0+..+1+...0= 1.
So yes, your inference is correct.